# Not reading $POST variables properly

Tags: php, post, yii2

I have some fields, that send me $POST on submit. I want to get one value, but I can't, maybe I'm just blind, but for me that's impossible what I see here. 
PHP:

```
$i = 0;
$ok = Yii::$app->request->post("Presentations");
$ok2 = $ok[$i]['place_name'];
var_dump($ok);
var_dump($ok2);
$i++;
```

First var_dump shows me what expected:

```
array (size=8)
  0 => 
    array (size=11)
      'gen_status_chechbox' => string '1' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'F17011201' (length=9)
      'presenter_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'presentation_assistants_ids' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2017-01-12' (length=10)
      'time' => string '12:00' (length=5)
      'place_id' => string '50' (length=2)
      'place_name' => string '0' (length=1)
      'place_city' => string '0' (length=1)
      'place_street' => string 'a' (length=1)
      'place_post_code' => string '00-000' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=10)
      'gen_status_chechbox' => string '1' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'F17011202' (length=9)
      'presenter_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'presentation_assistants_ids' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2017-01-12' (length=10)
      'time' => string '12:00' (length=5)
      'place_name' => string 'juz' (length=3)
      'place_city' => string 'nie' (length=3)
      'place_street' => string 'wiem' (length=4)
      'place_post_code' => string '55-999' (length=6)
  2 => 
    array (size=11)
      'gen_status_chechbox' => string '1' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'F17011301' (length=9)
      'presenter_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'presentation_assistants_ids' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2017-01-13' (length=10)
      'time' => string '12:00' (length=5)
      'place_id' => string '45' (length=2)
      'place_name' => string '0' (length=1)
      'place_city' => string '0' (length=1)
      'place_street' => string 'a' (length=1)
      'place_post_code' => string '00-000' (length=6)
```

And so on, up to 8, because I create 8 presentations. The second var_dump, shows me, no matter what, '0'. In second case, place_name is obviously 'juz', not '0'. I've been stuck with that for over 2 hours, and that's the point I came to have an apparent paradox, at least for me.
'0' is default value of 'place_name' input, but if $_POST has already different value, how can it appear later?

Comment: Please show us full loop code.

Comment: What shows `var_dump($ok[1]['place_name'])`?

Comment: @AntonRybalko it showed 0 every time, as I mantioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i see now.

I hope u have loop outside this code, BUT, u redefining `$i` every loop iteration. 
Take `$i = 0;` before loop statement or use `for()` like this:

```
$ok = Yii::$app->request->post("Presentations");
for($i = 0; $i < count($ok); $i++) {
   $ok2 = $ok[$i]['place_name'];
   var_dump($ok2);
}
```

Comment: Wow. I spent 2 hours trying to get to the $_POST is 100 possible ways. Didn't even think that I could have made such a trivial mistake. Thanks, @Yupik!